# Poisson's distribution upper limit

Tags: probability-distributions

Poisson distribution is defined as:
$$P(X=i)=\frac{\lambda^i}{i!}e^{-\lambda}$$
How do you find out upper limit for this distribution ?

Lets say that $\lambda=0.7$. My question is that is there any other way for solving $k$ from this equation than using sum like this:
$$P(X≈1)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{0.7^i}{i!}e^{-0.7}$$
For example with $k=11$ i would consider this close enough to one.
$$\sum_{i=0}^{11}\frac{0.7^i}{i!}e^{-0.7}≈1$$

Comment: You would need to select some negligible probability tolerance.

Comment: Then you can use the Lagrange remainder to show $P(X \geq k) \leq \lambda^k/k!$ and set that bound to be below your tolerance.